# Management methods and classes

Tags: java, string

I have a class called test and another call in this fraction are methods and classes from remote call test. 
    for this I make a method that changes the numerator by the denominator in a fraction. 
    Example if the user intruduce 3/4 in the result I 4/3

was the guide which can be performed on a Split string method but I get no help please.

Comment: Question is not clear at all. What are you trying to achieve and what error you are getting? please clarify..

Comment: Please post code you have so far.

Comment: check for zero as denominator while swapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string through the "/" sign and then simply do the following:

```
// Assume input is valid - no zero in denominator
String[] parts = input.split("/");
String answer = parts[1] + "/" + parts[2];
// return answer; -> if you need to return it from a method
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a `String`, you can split at the `/`.

```
String fraction = "3/4";
String[] splittedFraction = fraction.split("/");
```

Then you can piece it together like this.

```
System.out.println(splittedFraction[1] + "/" + splittedFraction[0]);
```

This is the [String API for Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).  I'd look for methods in there if you wanted to mess with Strings.